# RewriteRule with query string gets rewritten to /param/param/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, webmin

I have this rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/]+)/?$ /gallery.php?title=$1 [L]
```

However, when navigating to gallery/a/, the internal redirect is to :

```
gallery.php/a //(instead of: gallery.php?title=a)
```

What would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option `MultiViews` might be culprit here. Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Turn it off by using this line at top of your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Fantastic, that was it!